# Dockerfile contains a python script that writes to an output file, but the output file is not being created on the container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, devops

It's my first question, so be gentle :)

I've got a Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM centos:latest
Maintainer Liz Miller
LABEL description="Image Built with Dockerfile."
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install python-setuptools
RUN easy_install supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
RUN yum -y install which
RUN yum -y install git
RUN yum install python
COPY  myscript.py myscript.py
CMD ["python", "/myscript.py"]
```

And the myscript.py python script is:

```
text_file = open('output.txt', 'w')
text_file.write('Hello World')
text_file.close()
```

When I build the image from this Dockerfile, the image is being built with the script and runs it, I don't see the output.txt. It's just not being created. What is missing? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

1. Change your text_file to `/log/output.txt`
2. Build image doesn't run CMD.
3. After your build the image, you run your container, do

   ```
   docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/log:/log imagename
   ```

Your script write inside the container and exit right the way. So you won't see it in your current directory. The way to solve this is mount a host directory into the container, and let the script write inside it, so that the data can be persistent.

Comment: Hi Noam, thanks for replying. If build doesn't run CMD, then how should I run the script? You mentioned running the container with the output file, but what about the script?

Comment: After trying so much finally this simple solution worked for me, just wanted to say thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I've managed to solve the issue.
CMD indeed doesn't run commands, but RUN does.

I've changed my CMD line to this line:
RUN python myscript.py

That solved my issue, I was able to see the output file from the python script, on the container after building.